# async await performance?

Tags: c#, performance, async-await, theory

*(Just a theoretical question - for non-gui apps)*

Assuming I have this code with many `awaits`:

```
public async Task<T> ConsumeAsync()
    {
          await A();
          await b();
          await c();
          await d();
          //..
    }
```

Where each task can take a very short period of time ,

**Question** (again , theoretical)

There *could be*  a situation where the *overall time dealing* with all those "releasing back threads" and "fetching threads back" ( red & green here :)

[image]

Is taking *more* time than a single thread which could done all the work with a small amount of delay ,

I mean , I wanted to be the most productive , but instead , since all those switches back and forth - I actually lost productivity.

Can such scenario occur ?

Comment: It's a trade-off between performance and flexibility.

Comment: Why don't you try it out? Make your method calls extremely fast (put nothing in the method body). Then see if it takes more time than calling them synchronously. Run the code a thousand times and graph your results. But then again, you'll never have empty method bodies will you? `Async` and `await` are probably best used when you have a couple I/O tasks to perform.

Comment: Oh, and by the way, don't pre-optimize your code. Once you have bottlenecks or performance issues, then go optimize. Only if your positive a benefit can be gained should you pre-optimize.

Comment: using async is almost never faster. But it's more scalable.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456402.aspx

Comment: @mason another question would be whether writing async code from the beginning is premature optimisation, or it's the other way around.

Comment: @JohanBoulé It is often a good idea to write async code. It's more scalable and it gives you the option of using certain libraries that only expose async methods. You do need to know how and take special care with it however.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A `Task` object represent the deferred result of a pending operation. You don't have to use tasks and `async/await` if you don't have any pending operations. Otherwise, I believe `async`/`await` code is generally more efficient than its bare TPL `ContinueWith` analogue.

Let's do some timing:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        // async/await version
        static async Task<int> Test1Async(Task<int> task)
        {
            return await task;
        }

        // TPL version
        static Task<int> Test2Async(Task<int> task)
        {
            return task.ContinueWith(
                t => t.Result,
                CancellationToken.None,
                TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously,
                TaskScheduler.Default);
        }

        static void Tester(string name, Func<Task<int>, Task<int>> func)
        {
            var sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
            {
                func(Task.FromResult(0)).Wait();
            }
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}ms", name, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Tester("Test1Async", Test1Async);
            Tester("Test2Async", Test2Async);
        }
    }
}
```

The output:

```
Test1Async: 1582ms
Test2Async: 4975ms
```

So, by default, `await` continuations are handled more efficiently than `ContinueWith` continuations. Let's optimize this code slightly:

```
// async/await version
static async Task<int> Test1Async(Task<int> task)
{
    if (task.IsCompleted)
        return task.Result;
    return await task;
}

// TPL version
static Task<int> Test2Async(Task<int> task)
{
    if (task.IsCompleted)
        return Task.FromResult(task.Result);

    return task.ContinueWith(
        t => t.Result,
        CancellationToken.None,
        TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously,
        TaskScheduler.Default);
}
```

The output:

```
Test1Async: 1557ms
Test2Async: 429ms
```

Now the non-async version wins. In case with the `async` version, I believe this optimization has already been done internally by the `async/await` infrastructure.

Anyway, so far we've dealt only with completed tasks (`Task.FromResult`). Let's introduce the actual asynchrony (naturally, we'll do less iterations this time):

```
static Task<int> DoAsync()
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => tcs.SetResult(0));
    return tcs.Task;
}

static void Tester(string name, Func<Task<int>, Task<int>> func)
{
    ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(200, 200);
    var sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        func(DoAsync()).Wait();
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}ms", name, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

The output:

```
Test1Async: 4207ms
Test2Async: 4734ms
```

Now the difference is very marginal, although the `async` version still performs slightly better. Yet I think such gain is really neglectable, comparable to the actual cost of the asynchronous operation or to the cost of restoring the captured context for when `SynchronizationContext.Current != null`.

The bottom line is, if you deal with asynchronous tasks, go for `async`/`await` if you have a choice, not for performance reason but for ease of use, readability and maintainability.

Answer (score 29):

Yes, in theory. Not normally, in the real world.

In the common case, `async` is used for I/O-bound operations, and the overhead of thread management is undetectable in comparison to them. Most of the time, asynchronous operations either take a very long time (compared to thread management) or are already completed (e.g., a cache). Note that `async` has a "fast path" that kicks in if the operation is already completed, where it does not yield the thread.

For more information, see the [Zen of Async](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechDays/TechDays-2012-Belgium/239) and [Async Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456402.aspx).

Comment: Even if it's performed synchronously it will take longer as the TPL code has to run. Remember, it's as the OP pointed out a theoretical question.

Comment: @jgauffin: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "the TPL code has to run". There's no *scheduling* going on, if that's what you're thinking.

Comment: What I mean is that if you benchmark code using TPL and code doing the operations directly the latter will be faster as TPL adds some overhead (even if it's tiny).

Comment: @jgauffin `await` code that uses the fast path uses only a tiny amount of TPL (the equivalents of `Task.FromResult()` and `Task.Result`). Is that what you mean? It certainly doesn't do anything similar to `Task.Run()`, or anything like that.

Comment: I have thousand small awaits when writing to a file. But there is a 8MB buffer. So the real await is only hit when this buffer is full and has to be written on disk. This greatly improved the performance  instead of writing on disk thousand times

Answer (score 3):

> Can such scenario occur?

Absolutely. For this reason, you should be conscientious about where you use async code. Typically you're best using it for methods that will actually perform an asynchronous operation (disk or network I/O, for example). The time that these operations take usually far outweighs the cost of scheduling tasks on threads. Also, at the operating system level, these sorts of operations are inherently asynchronous, so you're actually *removing* a layer of abstraction by using async methods.

Even in these cases, though, you will likely not see a noticeable performance difference by switching to asynchronous code unless you are able to take advantage of concurrency. For example, the code you posted would probably see no real performance gain unless it were changed to something like this:

```
await Task.WhenAll(new[]{A(), B(), C(), D(), ...});
```

Comment: But this presumes async is always leveraging a thread.  Which is not so.

Comment: @KirkWoll: Please clarify. I specifically said that you should use async when you're performing operations that are actually asynchrnous. I can't think of any non-asynchronous operations that could be translated to async methods without leveraging a thread.

Comment: Take a look at Stephen Clearly's article, [There is no thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html); Erik Meijer once linked to it approvingly. :)

Comment: @KirkWoll: Sorry, but I just noticed your reply here several years later. That article is specifically talking about inherently _asynchronous_ operations, which (as I say in my answer) benefit from `async`/`await` and _concurrency_ (e.g. `Task.WhenAll()`) regardless of whether they are multi-threaded. Why are you saying my answer presumes async always leverages a thread?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can happen. Also do not forget that - all efficiency in there that you can program - the task system DOES have overhead.

If you get too granulkar with something like this, the synchronization overhead CAN kill you. THAT SAID: Tasks are quite efficienttly programmed.

But the old rule sticks: do not go super granular. SOmetimes optimization helps.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course it can happen. With all the overhead of the creating the state machine, yielding back and forth the control and using `IOCP` threads. But as said, the `TPL` is pretty optimized. For example, lets not forget that if your `TaskAwaitable` finishes quickly, there might be no overhead and it will execute synchronously, which might happen often with quick operations.