# ExecuteReaderAsync causes sql query to take longer to finish?

Tags: sql-server, async-await

I have this SQL server instance which is shared by several client-processes. I want queries to finish taking as little time as possible.

Say a call needs to read 1k to 10k records from this shared Sql Server. My natural choice would be to use ExecuteReaderAsync to take advantage of async benefits such as reusing threads.

I started wondering whether async will pose some overhead since execution might stop and resume for every call to ExecuteReaderAsync. That being true, seems that overall time for query to complete would be longer if compared to a implementation that uses ExecuteReader. Does that make (any) sense?

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23871806/async-await-performance

Answer (score 7):

Whether you use sync or async to call SQL Server makes no difference for the work that SQL Server does and for the CPU-bound work that ADO.NET does to serialize and deserialize request and response. So no matter what you chose the difference will be small.

Using async is not about saving CPU time. It is about saving memory (less thread stacks) and about having a nice programming model in UI apps.

In fact async never saves CPU time as far as I'm aware. It adds overhead. If you want to save CPU time use a synchronous approach.

On the server using async in low-concurrency workloads adds no value whatsoever. It adds development time and CPU cost.

Comment: I'm not concerned about client side CPU time. I'm concerned about the time Sql Server spends during the operation. After some study, I believe I want to use ExecuteReadAsync, store the tasks in a queue and handle those tasks later, after closing DB connection. Otherwise, the time spent handling the returned task will delay each ExecuteReadAsync call. This way, client will call ExecuteReadAsync one after the other without any delays. Does that make sense?

Comment: It is new to me that you want to execute multiple calls. That, of course, allows for parallelization. Can't you just run a query that returns all data at once? That can save extreme amounts of overhead. (I'll fully answer your comment when I have this information.)

Comment: Each query may return 1k to 10k records. That's a ExecuteReadAsync for each. Each record has a binary fields which needs to be parsed.

Comment: I'd use any standard parallelization strategy for this. Like PLINQ or Parallel.ForEach or multiple async methods each executing a query and processing the results. It doesn't matter much whether you use async IO or sync IO for this. You cannot make the network or server faster by changing the way you invoke a method. The more parallelism you have the more the memory benefits of using async IO come into play. It#s not going to help for total time spent, though. Why would it?

Comment: Well, the time client spends interacting with server is:
  (#records * (timeof(ExecuteRead) + timeof(HandlingReadData)))
vs
  (#records * timeof(ExecuteReadAsync))

Comment: You're right, you should probably have a certain optimal number of database operations in-flight at any given time. Whether you do it sync or async again does not matter. Do you think it matters?

Comment: You're right. I can I achieve the same "throughput" with sync.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between the async approach and the sync approach is that the async call will cause the compiler to generate a state machine, whereas the sync call will simply block while the work agains't the database is being done.

IRL, the best way to choose is to benchmark both approaches. As usr said, usually those differrences are neglectable compared to the time the query takes to execute. Async will shine brighter in places where it may save resources such as allocating a new thread

There are many posts about async performance:

1. [*Async await performance*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23871806/async-await-performance)
2. [*The zen of async: best practices for best performance*](http://channel9.msdn.com/events/BUILD/BUILD2011/TOOL-829T)
3. [*Async Performance: Understanding the Costs of Async and Await*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456402.aspx)