# System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder::Start has significant self time

Tags: c#, async-await, profiling

I'm [profiling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/performance-explorer) our C# .NET application, and I'm noticing that the method the method `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder::Start` is appearing multiple times, taking up about 3-4 seconds of Self Time of my 1 minute sample (meaning that it's spending about 3-4 seconds in the task infrastructure).

I understand that this method is used by the compiler to implement the `async`/`await` language construct in C#. What, generally, is in it that would cause it to block or otherwise take up a lot of time? Is there any way to improve our method so that it spends less time in this infrastructure?

**EDIT:** Here's a somewhat lengthy, but still self-contained, code sample demonstrating the problem, essentially doing a parallel merge sort on two very large arrays:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AsyncAwaitSelfTimeTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random random = new Random();

            int[] arrayOne = GenerateArray(50_000_000, random.Next);
            double[] arrayTwo = GenerateArray(50_000_000, random.NextDouble);

            Comparer<int> comparerOne = Comparer<int>.Create((a, b) =>
            {
                if (a < b) return -1;
                else if (a > b) return 1;
                else return 0;
            });
            Comparer<double> comparerTwo = Comparer<double>.Create((a, b) =>
            {
                if (a < b) return -1;
                else if (a > b) return 1;
                else return 0;
            });

            var sortTaskOne = Task.Run(() => MergeSort(arrayOne, 0, arrayOne.Length, comparerOne));
            var sortTaskTwo = Task.Run(() => MergeSort(arrayTwo, 0, arrayTwo.Length, comparerTwo));

            Task.WaitAll(sortTaskOne, sortTaskTwo);
            Console.Write("done sorting");
        }

        static T[] GenerateArray<T>(int length, Func<T> getFunc)
        {
            T[] result = new T[length];
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                result[i] = getFunc();
            }
            return result;
        }

        static async Task MergeSort<T>(T[] array, int start, int end, Comparer<T> comparer)
        {
            if (end - start <= 16)
            {
                SelectionSort(array, start, end, comparer);
            }
            else
            {
                int mid = start + (end - start) / 2;

                Task firstTask = Task.Run(() => MergeSort(array, start, mid, comparer));
                Task secondTask = Task.Run(() => MergeSort(array, mid, end, comparer));

                await Task.WhenAll(firstTask, secondTask);

                int firstIndex = start;
                int secondIndex = mid;
                T[] dest = new T[end - start];
                for (int i = 0; i < dest.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (firstIndex >= mid)
                    {
                        dest[i] = array[secondIndex++];
                    }
                    else if (secondIndex >= end)
                    {
                        dest[i] = array[firstIndex++];
                    }
                    else if (comparer.Compare(array[firstIndex], array[secondIndex]) < 0)
                    {
                        dest[i] = array[firstIndex++];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dest[i] = array[secondIndex++];
                    }
                }

                dest.CopyTo(array, start);
            }
        }

        static void SelectionSort<T>(T[] array, int start, int end, Comparer<T> comparer)
        {
            // note: using selection sort here to prevent time variability
            for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
            {
                int minIndex = i;
                for (int j = i + 1; j < end; j++)
                {
                    if (comparer.Compare(array[j], array[minIndex]) < 0)
                    {
                        minIndex = j;
                    }
                }
                T temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[minIndex];
                array[minIndex] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the performance profile of this code, the two copies of `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder::Start` (one for each generic value type) take up most of the self-processor time, with the two `MergeSort` methods only taking up a very small fraction of the self-processor time. Similar behavior was also noted when `Task.Run` was not used (thus utilizing only a single processor).

**EDIT 2:** Thank you very much for your answers so far. I originally thought that the fact that `Task<TResult>` was being used was part of the problem (since it was being used in the original code), hence my structure of copying arrays instead of sorting in place. However, I recognize now that that is irrelevant, so I changed the code snippet above to instead do a merge sort in place. I have also reduced the task count by introducing a non-trivial sequential cutoff (doing selection sort for the sake of tightly bound time), as well as using `Comparer` objects to prevent boxing allocations of the array elements (and thus reducing the profiling interference caused by the garbage collector).

However, the same pattern, that of `AsyncTaskMethodBuilder::Start` taking significant self time, still exists and can still be found in the profiling results.

**EDIT 3:** To clarify, the answer I am/was looking for is not "why is this code slow?", but "why is the .NET profiler telling me that most of the cost is spent inside a method I have no control over?" The accepted answer helped me identify the problem, which was that most of the logic was inside a generated type that the profiler does not include.

Comment: Can you post a self-contained code sample reproducing that? Normally, the overhead of async/await is quite low, comparable to the overhead of the actual async operation, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23878905/1768303).

Comment: I'll see what I can do. It'll take me a while, because I think part of the problem is that our project is so large and spans many assemblies, and that these Task Builder methods have to be regenerated in all of them.

Comment: async is cheap. That said, running your code through dotTrace shows that your MergeSort method is called 40 millions times. As basic mathematics will show, `cheap * 40.000.000 = expensive`. GC is hogging 20% of CPU time, then the task infrastructure (creating tasks, awaiting, scheduling the threadpool, flowing the context) is using 50% of what's left. Your code is deeply inefficient: rather than creating 2n tasks, you should manually make `Environment.ProcessorCount` partitions, then run a single-threaded algorithm on each of those partitions.

Comment: `Is there any way to improve our method so that it spends less time in this infrastructure?` Unfortunately, this is no magic. In your sample, I'm saving only 5% (going from 17 seconds of execution to 16) by switching from async to tasks with ContinueWith. Tasks are a convenient tool, but hide a complex machinery that has an induced cost. If tasks use too much resource, all you can do is using less of them. Often, `async` method can be rewritten to just return the task allocated by a child method (instead of creating a new one), thus saving a bit of time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting. I took your sample and altered the `MergeSort` async method to be non-async. Now a profiling session takes ~33 sec to complete (vs ~36 sec for the async version, both using Release config). The non-async version looks like this:

```
    static Task<T[]> MergeSort<T>(T[] src) where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        if (src.Length <= 1)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(src);
        }
        else
        {
            int mid = src.Length / 2;
            T[] firstHalf = new T[mid];
            T[] secondHalf = new T[src.Length - mid];
            Array.Copy(src, 0, firstHalf, 0, mid);
            Array.Copy(src, mid, secondHalf, 0, src.Length - mid);

            Task<T[]> firstTask = Task.Run(() => MergeSort(firstHalf));
            Task<T[]> secondTask = Task.Run(() => MergeSort(secondHalf));

            return Task.WhenAll(firstTask, secondTask).ContinueWith(
                continuationFunction: _ =>
                {
                    T[] firstDest = firstTask.Result;
                    T[] secondDest = secondTask.Result;
                    int firstIndex = 0;
                    int secondIndex = 0;

                    T[] dest = new T[src.Length];
                    for (int i = 0; i < dest.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (firstIndex >= firstDest.Length)
                        {
                            dest[i] = secondDest[secondIndex++];
                        }
                        else if (secondIndex >= secondDest.Length)
                        {
                            dest[i] = firstDest[firstIndex++];
                        }
                        else if (firstDest[firstIndex].CompareTo(secondDest[secondIndex]) < 0)
                        {
                            dest[i] = firstDest[firstIndex++];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dest[i] = secondDest[secondIndex++];
                        }
                    }

                    return dest;
                },
                cancellationToken: System.Threading.CancellationToken.None,
                continuationOptions: TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously,
                scheduler: TaskScheduler.Default);
        }
    }
```

So, for this particular example, the async/await overhead seems to be ~3 seconds. This is more than I expected, but it's certainly not a bottleneck here.

Regarding this observation:

> In the performance profile of this code, the two copies of
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder::Start (one for
>   each generic value type) take up most of the self-processor time, with
>   the two MergeSort methods only taking up a very small fraction of the
>   self-processor time.

I haven't analyzed the compiler-generated code for this particular async method, but I suspect `MergeSort` just contains a short prolog/epilog code, while the actual CPU-intensive code is indirectly invoked by `AsyncTaskMethodBuilder::Start`.

Comment: Hmm... interesting! I will take a look at the disassembly at some point. I've since edited the sample to sort in place, but the problem manifest in the original question is still there.

Comment: As you suspected, the compiled `MergeSort` method does indeed only hold a short prologue/epilogue - the actual code is found in a generated inner type. I'm not sure why the `AsyncTaskMethodBuilder::Start` is reporting all of it's execution time as self time (since this class exists), but your explanation seems plausible.

Answer (score 5):

The problem you got here is that you spawn that many tasks that you overload the normal task pool, causing .NET to spawn additional tasks. Since you keep creating new tasks all the way down to the length of the array being `1`. `AsyncTaskMethodBuilder::Start` starts being a significant time consumer, once it needs to create new tasks to continue the execution and can't reuse tasks from the pool.

There are a couple of things you need to change to get some performance into your function:

**First: Clean up you `await`'s**

```
Task<T[]> firstTask = Task.Run(() => MergeSort(firstHalf));
Task<T[]> secondTask = Task.Run(() => MergeSort(secondHalf));

await Task.WhenAll(firstTask, secondTask);

T[] firstDest = await firstTask;
T[] secondDest = await secondTask;
```

This is already a problem. Remember that every `await` counts. Event if the `Task` is already completed, `await` still splits the function at this point, releases the current `Task` and continues the remaining function in a new `Task`. This switch takes time. Not much, but this happens so often in your function and it will be measurable.

`Task.WhenAll` already returns the result value you need.

```
Task<T[]> firstTask = Task.Run(() => MergeSort(firstHalf));
Task<T[]> secondTask = Task.Run(() => MergeSort(secondHalf));

T[][] dests = await Task.WhenAll(firstTask, secondTask);

T[] firstDest = dests[0];
T[] secondDest = dests[1];
```

This way you can reduce the amount of task switches in your function.

**Second: Reduce the amount of `Task` instances created.**

Tasks are a great tool to distribute work on your different CPU cores, but you have to make sure that they are busy. There is a in creating a new `Task` and you have to be sure that it is worth it.

I suggest adding a threshold to the point where new `Task`s are created. If the portions you are working on get too small, you shouldn't create new `Task` instances, but instead call the functions directly.

For example:

```
T[] firstDest;
T[] secondDest;
if (mid > 100) 
{
  Task<T[]> firstTask = Task.Run(() => MergeSort(firstHalf));
  Task<T[]> secondTask = Task.Run(() => MergeSort(secondHalf));

  T[][] dests = await Task.WhenAll(firstTask, secondTask);

  firstDest = dests[0];
  secondDest = dests[1];
} 
else 
{
  firstDest = MergeSort(firstHalf);
  secondDest = MergeSort(secondHalf);
}
```

You should try different values and see how this changes thing. `100` is just a value I'd start with, but you can choose any other. This will reduce the amount of tasks that don't have much to do by a significant number. Basically the value determines how much remaining work is acceptable for one task to be handled.

Lastly you should think about handling your `array` instances differently. If you tell your function the start position and the length of the portion of the array they are expected to work in, you should be able to improve the performance even more, because you don't have to copy the arrays thousands of times.

Comment: Thank you - these are some good insights. Since I realized that I actually have no good reason to return the arrays at all (my main motivation was to cause the C# compiler to generate multiple templates, which my templated `MergeSort` was already doing, I have since edited the sample to sort in place.

Comment: for future readers: threadpool starvation is the keyword here.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, using async/await has measurable overhead when called in a tight loop. You shouldn't need Tasks for easy CPU-bound work like sorting an array.

If an async method usually finishes synchronously, it *may* be possible to improve performance by using [ValueTask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#generalized-async-return-types) in C# 7.

The main problem with your sample code is that MergeSort allocates far too much temporary garbage. I see a 40x speedup simply by switching to the builtin Sort method, e.g.:

```
Array.Sort(arrayOne)
```

Comment: Those are some good points. Since I realized that I have no good reason to allocate so much temporary garbage (and thus require the garbage collector to interrupt everything), I edited the sample in the question above to sort in place.

Answer (score 0):

> What, generally, is in it that would cause it to block or otherwise take up a lot of time?

[Every asynchronous method starts execution synchronously](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html). In terms of the async state machine, you can think of your method as being "split" into multiple parts, with each `await` being a division point.

So, I'd expect that `Start` would execute `MergeSort` up until the first `await` - i.e., creating two arrays and copying the entire input array into them.

Comment: Sure, but it seems that would register in the CPU profiler as being part of `MergeSort`. What I'm noting is what appears to be blocking in `Start` itself (i.e. the CPU directly executing C# or VB code written by the C# devs at Microsoft).