# why Asynchronous delegates incur a surprising overhead [c#]

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

i read this book [c# 6.0 in a Nutshell]

I had a question while reading in 619 page subject to Asynchronous delegates

> Asynchronous delegates incur a surprising overhead—and are painfully
>   redundant with tasks:

```
Func<string> foo = () => { Thread.Sleep(1000); return "foo"; };
Task.Run (foo).ContinueWith (ant => Console.WriteLine (ant.Result));
```

why Asynchronous delegates incur a surprising overhead ?

Comment: The answer to this question is possibly covered in [async await performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23871806/async-await-performance) and it's links to [Zen of Async](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechDays/TechDays-2012-Belgium/239) and [Async Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456402.aspx)

Comment: The task continuation pattern you have posted is pretty much dead in this day and age. It's been superseded by `async/await`. Don't get me wrong: there are still legitimate uses for `ContinueWith`, but they are reserved for advanced scenarios that don't crop up very often.

Comment: Not seeing the forest for the trees, `Thread.Sleep(1000)` is terribly inefficient for a `Task`!