# ASP.NET Core MemoryCache GetOrCreateAsync overhead of async and await

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-core, async-await

First a little bit of context:

Currently, we are using the ASP.NET Core MemoryCache [MemoryCache Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

On the `IMemoryCache` interface there is a method called `GetOrCreateAsync(...)` where I can pass in a factory func `Func<ICacheEntry, Task<TItem>> factory`

Since this is an async method signature I have to implement `async await` all the way through (sometimes a callstack of around 8 Methods), even though the cache hit itself is synchronous. In my scenario, I hit the cache around 200-2500 times per request. Some entries I have to refresh every 60minutes some of them just every day.

Now the question:

My current understanding is, that .NET Core has to create a state machine for every call, even though I just hit the cache in a synchronous way, because of its method signature. Does one of you know how big the overhead of this is? Would it make more sense to create a synchronous factory (It's a Web-API-call) with a little bit of blocking so that I can use `GetOrCreate(...)`? Or maybe some of you have a completely different idea.

Hope you get my pain point.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/ (to compare `GetOrCreateAsync` vs `GetOrCreate`)

Comment: "...that .NET Core has to create a state machine...". No, .NET Core has absolutely nothing to do with async and await. It's the c# compiler that does it, not the runtime

Comment: Possible duplicate of [async await performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23871806/async-await-performance)

Comment: `async` allows better **utilisation** of threads. So in theory the overhead of context switching etc. is made up by allowing more "processes" to use a limited number of threads in any one time. This is only relevant in IO bound processes though, as the process needs to be waiting for external resources and not using the CPU to relinquish this overhead to another thread. So CPU bound processes get limited (zero or worse) performance gain. This is all theoretical though and really the only way to test this is to...test it...yourself.

Comment: Also remember [premature optimization is the root of all evil](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth)

Comment: @mjwills To stay in the context of your link. I don't need to ride a horse which is already ridden by others and they already know that one horse is slower than the other. If I have to try out everything myself, why should I ask questions on SO?

Comment: @VSDekar You should be asking questions on SO *after* you have done your research looked at existing resources on a subject, and attempted to solve your problem yourself.

Comment: @Servy Believe me, I have done a lot of research. And I have tried to phrase my question as accurate as possible for a very specific product which is in use 100 of times. If i can save myself several hours of implementing a similar thing with one question then I think it's worth to give it a try. All I ask is if someone already has some knowledge about the `MemoryCache`in their own solution.

Answer (score 2):

You have a number of confusions here. First and most importantly, the delegate is not an async delegate, but rather a *task-returning delegate*. It's typical to conflate the two because you generally only return tasks from async operations, but you do not have to. To satisfy the delegate, you simply need to use `Task.FromResult(foo)`, where `foo` is whatever you're returning ultimately. Importantly, that return can be satisfied synchronously, so, if the underlying process is synchronous, there's no need to involve async/await at all from here on down.

Second, `await` will by default create a `SynchronizationContext`. This exists in case of a thread switch, as anything that's thread local needs to be moved over to the new thread to prevent missing references. That involves adding stuff to the heap, and yes, can degrade performance. However, if you're not utilizing thread locals and/or there's no possibility of a thread switch, you don't need this. In such cases, you can call `ConfigureAwait(false)` on the asynchronous method. ASP.NET Core, in particular, does not use thread locals at all (cross-cutting dependencies are satisfied via dependency injection). As a result, it's *always* safe to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` and you should actually be adding that to every single async operation you perform. In this particular case, a `SynchronizationContext` is doubly useless, since you operation is sync, meaning no thread switch could occur anyways.