# ASP.NET Core Identity async Overhead in Custom Stores

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-identity

While developing a ASP.NET Core Web Application I needed to add ASP.NET Core Identity to my Project. However I needed only a small part of Identity because e.g. I know that this application will never allow third party logins.
Therefore I decided to write my custom stores. While searching the internet for good solutions on how to do that I often saw a Implementation like this:

```
    public Task SetUserNameAsync(ApplicationUser user, string userName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        if (user == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(user));

        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userName))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userName));

        user.Username = userName;

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

or

```
    public Task<string> GetUserNameAsync(ApplicationUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        if (user == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(user));

        return Task.FromResult(user.Username);
    }
```

as far as I understand it that would be called in a fashion like this:

```
var user = await store.GetUserNameAsync(_user, CancellationToken.None);
```

but wouldn't that basically create a State Machine for a getter/setter that should just immediately return without any big overhead or is there any good benefit doing it like this that I am not seeing right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identity is a framework that is highly customizable. E.g. you could create your own UserManager while still using the standard SignInManager that handles login, logout, ...

What you found seems to be implementations of UserManager.GetUserNameAsync()> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.getusernameasync?view=aspnetcore-2.1

The reason why this method returns a task is, that the implementation *could* required db or network access.

If you really don't want to use anything of Identity and do everyting yourself, there's no need to return a task. But to be hornest, I'd suggest to think twice if this is a good approach.

Comment: I understand where you  are coming from however why should I use access to the Db in my store in a getter/setter (if thats really only a getter/setter) if I could just call the UpdateAsync Method to propagate changes to e.g. the Username of my User. And just for Clarification I want to use Identity just not all features because I know that I don't need some of them.

Comment: Not sure if I got your point. Yes, GetuserNameAsync is simply "I have a user object here and want to get the value that I should use as username". (could be the value of Username property or Email property or result of something like mydb.GetUserNameFor(user.Id). UserManager.UpdateAsync is made to update the user in your database, so something completly different.

Comment: I try to clarify. if I have my GetUserNameAsync and I give it my ApplicationUser object, from where I want the value lets say username from. Why should i mark this as async and give someone the option to await it. Is there such a thing as a real world example where I would need to do async Operations especially if I have my ApplicationUser class right there that has all of his values set? Of course I could go to my Db and fetch a "new" ApplicationUser to read out the value but if I have the ApplicationUser with all value why should I ever do that?

Comment: As your wrote, in most cases there's absolutly no need to do an async operation here. But as GetUserNameAsync is part of a large framework, we need ONE defined method that other classes can use and other setups could in theory require a db lookup here. Only if we have always the same signature, other framework classes can use this method. And because of this 'other setups could require async' this ONE signature is async. Hold in mind, that the overhead is very small.

Comment: Ah okay thank you for the clarification. I was just a little bit worried because I thought I read somewhere that the overhead for creating this in my case useless state mashine when calling GetUserNameAsync was quite large.

Comment: Might not be the best benchmark, but just as an example (first google result I found): We're talking about 0.0016ms. (1582ms for 1.000.000 calls and the function call itself is included): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23871806/async-await-performance